# C program Array as a parameter

Tags: c

I write a function like:

```
void func1(char chx[], int y) 
  {
    int wsn = 0;

    wsn = *(int *) (&chx[2]);
    if (wsn == 0) {
    ...
    }
 }
```

Compiler works well, no warning, no error. But when the code is running, seems it get a wild pointer. the code crashed.

Wonder why it was crashed

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info. Use a debugger to find out what is happening. It depends on how your `func1` was called, and of the compiler, the optimization, the processor, the ABI. Perhaps an alignment issue.

Comment: because 1. a pointer is not an array, 2. an array is not a pointer, and 3. this violates the strict aliasing rule so it has UB.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Also, `chx` is a pointer, so `&chx != chx`.

Comment: Checked my code again, it's like : wsn = *(int *) (&chx[2]);                                         I think &chx[2] == &(*(chx+2)), so, it's not a pointer to the pointer bug.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays, when passed to functions, decays to pointers. That means that in `func1` the variable `chx` is a pointer, so doing `&chx` gives you a pointer to the pointer.

The solution: Don't use the address-of operator `&`.

Comment: Thanks,I am confused it with array, think &array can get the array address.

Comment: Sorry, I checked my code again, the usage is like:      wsn = *(int *) (&chx[2]);           not        wsn = *(int *) (&chx);

Comment: Is your intent to get the **3rd** element of `chx`?